# Failing maven-build when Gatling-test has too high fail-percentage

Tags: scala, maven, maven-plugin, gatling

I am trying to run a simple performance-test through Gatling. I use maven to run the process. In order to easely pick up when changes in the code breaks my gatling-tests I want the maven-build to fail. I have made sure to add `<failOnError>true</failOnError>` in my pom.xml file.

My current script is something like this:

```
class MySim extends Simulation {
    val httpProtocol = http.baseURL("http://localhost:8080")
    val scn = scenario("Test")
         .exec(http("request_1")
           .get("""/helloworld""")
           .check(status.is(200))
         )
    setUp(scn.inject(ramp(1 users) over (1 seconds))).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

I run the build using maven (with the gatling-maven-plugin) using `mvn clean gatling:execute` which will allways succeed. (even when the server isn't running). I am looking for a way to make sure the maven builds fails when gatling-test fails (or has a too high fail-percentage).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I figured out a solution: All I had to do was add assertions to the setUp, with the criteria I wanted. So the following code would fail the maven-build if the successrate was lover than 90%.

```
setUp(scn.inject( ... ))
    .protocols(httpProtocol)
    .assertions(
        global.successfulRequests.percent.greaterThan(90)
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the [Assertions](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0-RC3/general/assertions.html?highlight=assertions) API.